# Missing vmlinux error when using the tool, penguins-eggs

Tags: command-line

When I use eggs to create an ISO of my system with the command

```
sudo eggs produce --basename <NAME> --standard`
```

I get the error

> command: produce --basename,Abibi,--standard
> creating configuration's files...
> /boot/vmlinuz--6.5.0-14-generic not exists!

Running `sudo eggs config` does not help either with the same error.

Comment: On what version of Ubuntu are you and how did you obtain the "eggs" software? The Ubuntu distribution has no eggs command, as far as I can tell. You're more likely to find support on the web site of the makers of that software.